# 3 apps full CI/CD with Docker-compose + GitHub Actions + DigitalOcean

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, digital-ocean, cicd

My source code repo is hosted on GitHub and I'm wondering how to implement a CI/CD github actions pipeline for testing, build and deploy of my MERN application to DigitalOcean. I have admin_frontend, user_frontend, backend folders in the root.

What I want to achieve if I push to master branch, run CI/CD workflows so:

- Build apps (production react build for 2 frontend)
- run tests (I have only some Jest test cases in 1 frontend app)
- deploy to my digital ocean droplet

*I don't know how to solve this since I have NOT just 1 frontend app in my github repository but 2 frontend and 1 backend app. If you have any workflow template for that structure, idea how to do this I appreciate it.*

**Do I need to create just one .github/workflows/main.yml in the root or 3 into all apps?**

Currenctly I can deploy to my Digital Ocean droplet the 3 apps by running this script:

```
#build admin frontend
docker build -t admin-fe ./admin_frontend_app
docker save -o ./admin-fe.tar admin-fe

#build backend and frontend
docker build -t main-be ./backend & docker build -t main-fe ./frontend
docker save -o ./main-be.tar main-be & docker save -o ./main-fe.tar main-fe

#deploy services
ssh root@IPADDRESS "pwd && mkdir -p ~/apps/mern && cd ~/apps/mern && ls -al && echo 'im in' && rm admin-fe.tar && rm main-be.tar && rm main-fe.tar &> /dev/null" 

#upload admin-fe.tar to VM via ssh
scp ./admin-fe.tar root@IPADDRESS:~/apps/mern/
#upload main-be.tar and main-fe.tar to VM via ssh
scp ./main-be.tar ./main-fe.tar root@IPADDRESS:~/apps/mern/
ssh root@IPADDRESS "cd ~/apps/mern && ls -1 *.tar | xargs --no-run-if-empty -L 1 docker load -i"

#sudo docker compose up
ssh root@IPADDRESS "cd ~/apps/mern && sudo docker-compose up"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have one single repository it can be convenient creating a single workflow which runs all steps:

- build and test user frontend
- build admin frontend
- build backend
- deploy apps (you could look at `digitalocean/action-doctl@v2` to accomplish this)

The workflow is convenient when you want to deploy them all at once (also I think you wouldn't do this upon each `git push` otherwise every change would redeploy them all).

The option you mention (3 workflows) is also a valid solution when you want to keep the components independent: for example build/push the admin frontend without affecting the others.

Comment: Thanks! Actually single workflow would be better and steps you mentioned is great! Unfortunately I don't know if there's any way to specify which is be folder, which is fe,etc. That's the problem - I didn't find any template for this cicd structure. Maybe I'll also use tags & run cicd only on pull requests, so i.e. a new version is out than that will be deployed. I'm looking a best-practice way which is not too compicated to achieve and I can use for this !

Answer (score 0):

I have just started creating a MERN Docker Deployment Boilerplate using Github Actions, it's still Work in Progress at https://github.com/mdarif/project-management

Haven't been using Digital Ocean but more or less workflows should remain same in case of MERN app.

Our workflow YAML file is split into 2 halves one for Server Deployment & Client Deployment.

```
name: Docker CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "Client-Deployment"
  Client-Deployment:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest



  # This workflow contains a single job called "Server-Deployment"
  Server-Deployment:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

You may check the complete code on github [repo](https://github.com/mdarif/project-management) shared earlier.